# ngx-formly how to evaluate whether a multicheckbox answer is chosen

Tags: angular, angular-forms, ngx-formly

I am using ngx-formly and running into an issue with expressions on multicheckbox. I am attempting to see if the value of "Other" was selected. The box continually displays regardless of selected value and throws the following error.

The error thrown:
js:73781 ERROR TypeError: [Formly Error] [Expression "hide"] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Other') at eval (eval at evalStringExpression

The following JSON is what I am using in the form:

```
    {
      "key": "what_are_your_sources_of_income",
      "type": "multicheckbox",
      "templateOptions": {
        "type": "array"
      },
      "props": {
        "label": "What are your sources of income?",
        "defaultValue": null,
        "required": true,
        "options": [
          {
            "label": "Cool stuff",
            "value": "Cool stuff"
          },
          {
            "label": "Other",
            "value": "Other"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "other_sources_of_income",
      "type": "input",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "props": {
        "label": "Other sources of income:",
        "placeholder": "",
        "className": "nested-field"
      },
      "expressions": {
        "hide": "!model.what_are_your_sources_of_income.Other",
        "props.required": "model.what_are_your_sources_of_income.Other"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the expressions of "other_sources_of_income", you need to `null`
check the "what_are_your_sources_of_income" before looking for the "Options" value.
Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvtjyt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

```
{
  key: 'other_sources_of_income',
  type: 'input',
  defaultValue: '',
  props: {
    label: 'Other sources of income:',
    placeholder: '',
    className: 'nested-field',
  },
  expressions: {
    hide: '!model.what_are_your_sources_of_income?.Other',
    "props.required": "model.what_are_your_sources_of_income?.Other"
  },
}
```